# angular 6 profile card onhover

Tags: angular, angular-material, tooltip

I need to display an employee's profile card onhover on an column in a table.  I thought to use a tooltip with an image and text for the employee's name and phone number, similar to #2 in the image provided.

But, based on design best practices @ https://material.io/design/components/tooltips.html, using a tooltip for such information should not be done.  See the text (do's and donts) at the bottom of the image provided.  Unfortunately, the site doesn't state what should be used.

Any ideas and reference to examples is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: could be a simple div using ngIf

Comment: Is there any reason you wouldn't be able to code this by hand?

Comment: I can code this by hand.  But, would like to have an example to review, which follows best practices with Angular Material.  I could create a div, but how to I show the contents like a tooltip over a particular column a table?

Comment: The point of that document is to say that you _shouldn't_ do it for **visual/usability design reasons**. There's probably no technical limitation.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip I created my own tooltip today instead of using materials

Comment: As @DavidWalschots pointed out, there are design reasons why you shouldn't do it, but there is no technical limitation with MatTooltip if you decide to do it anyway. So the question is why shouldn't you do it? The answer is because a tooltip is not a good choice as an interactive element (from both a design and a technical perspective) because it is temporary. In this particular situation, I would recommend selective disclosure - possibly an expansion panel - via click (not hover).

Comment: Tooltips should preferably contain only text, you are looking for a popover element, see https://github.com/ncstate-sat/popover for a material-cdk based implementation